# Unity - Best way to move a transform to a specific position (on a particular speed) without physics?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how should I make a transform move to a particular point (without using physics).

Currently I make my object look at the target position:

```
transform.LookAt(m_TargetPos, UnityEngine.Vector3.up);
```

and then I update its position every frame using a certain speed:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * (m_Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Finally I use a `sqrMagnitude` to know if the transform reached the position:

```
if ((transform.position - m_TargetPos).sqrMagnitude < 0.0025f) // 0.0025 = 0.05f * 0.05f
        return true;
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes the entity goes beyond the target position advancing forwards forever.

How should I code the condition so it never goes beyond the target position?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jichael that's not how you use `Lerp` though

Comment: Woops, wrote too fast, you use a delta that you increment everyframe or something, my bad !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) which avoids overshooting in the end:

> Calculate a position between the points specified by current and target, moving no farther than the distance specified by maxDistanceDelta.

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, m_TargetPos, m_Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

For checking if you already reached the position you can either simply use [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html)

```
if (transform.position == m_TargetPos)
    return true;
```

this has a precision of `1e-5` so it equals using [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) with a threshold of `0.00001`

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, m_TargetPos) < 0.00001f)
    return true;
```

here you can now define a wider threshold

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, m_TargetPos) < 0.0025f)
    return true;
```

or also a more precise one e.g.

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, m_TargetPos) < 0.0000001f)
    return true;
```

depending on your needs.

---

If you want to use [`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) I would rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and do in short

```
// TODO: either block concurrent routines with a bool flag
// TODO: or stop the running routine before starting a new one
StartCoroutine(MoveTo(targetPosition, speed));

...

private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 targetPos, float speed)
{
    var currentPos = transform.position;
    var distance = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, targetPos);
    // TODO: make sure speed is always > 0
    var duration = distance / speed;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
        // always a factor between 0 and 1
        var factor = timePassed / duration;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, targetPos, factor);

        // increase timePassed with Mathf.Min to avoid overshooting
        timePassed += Math.Min(Time.deltaTime, duration - timePassed);

        // "Pause" the routine here, render this frame and continue
        // from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.position = targetPos;

    // Something you want to do when moving is done
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, acording to this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html you still need to check the distance? would I not have the same problem that I am having now?

Comment: @Cris Not the same. You still have to check the distance somehow yes. But `MoveTowards` explicitly avoids any overshooting so you don't have to take care about that, only check when the object reaches the target position .. if you even need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. MoveTowards worked like a charm.